# How can I set the collection cell width to dynamic stretch to phone width

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can I set the collection cell view to dynamically stretch to iphone screen width (e.g. iphone 5s, iphone 6 plus)?

I tried:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    (ResultCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellClass
                                                                      forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.bounds = CGRectMake(0,0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 150);

    return cell;
}
```

That does not work. I don't see the content get stretch to the right side of the screen.

I have tried adding this delegate method:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
            layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
            sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGSize cellSize;

    cellSize.width = self.view.bounds.size.width;

    // body view height
    cellSize.height = 150;

    return cellSize;
}
```

I have set breakpoints in the method, but that method never get called?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same issue with the same use case. I finally ended up doing

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(collectionView.bounds.size.width, 150);
}
```

This changes the size of each item (cell) of the collection view. Hence you could change the size of each cell using this. Here i need the cell width to be same as of my UICollectionView so i passed the UICollectionview's width and specific height that i desired. Hope this would help.

Also there is no need to set the cell bounds in `- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` as the size gets set via `- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Also make sure that you have attached the desired `Delegates & DataSources` to the UICollectionView

Comment: Thank you. In the xib file for the Cell, I have hardcode width to be 280. So even if I dynamically set the cell width in collectionView layout(), it get override in the xib file. How can I not set the width in the xib file for the cell?

Comment: Have you attached the desired DELEGATES for the UICollectionView. Because it doesn't matter even if you set the Width in XIB. If you have implemented the Delegate (Flowlayout), then it should get override and accept the new values regardless of the value(280) that has been set via XIB.

Comment: Make sure that you have attached `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` for UICollectionView.

Comment: Yes. I have attached the delegates for UICollectionView. I have set breakpoints in sizeForItemAtIndexPath and it does break. I am returning return CGSizeMake(width, 120); But when I run it , I still see content squeeze to the left side, with right side has empty space.

Comment: Have you checked the width of your UICollectionview. Try to print the values using `NSLog(@"the frame : %@", NSStringFromCGRect(collectView.bounds));` Check if the width of your UICollectionView is Greater then what you are setting for UICollectionViewCel. As without seeing a much code, i cannot comment further.

Comment: Also check for `minimumLineSpacing` and `minimumInteritemSpacing` as they are also a factor in forming the cell size. All a part of `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout `.

Comment: Thanks your help. You are right the collectView.bounds is smaller than the width for the cell. How can I dynamically set the width of the collectView to match the phone width?

Comment: Best would be to use [Autolayout](http://www.raywenderlich.com/83276/beginning-adaptive-layout-tutorial). Please accept the answer if it helps.

Comment: There are two ways of doing it. Either you could implement `Autolayout` which i think you are unable to do. Second would be to `reset the frame of the UICOllectionView` in `-(void)viewdidappear` so that it could be resized to the size of the current device.

Comment: Thanks again. What do you mean by 'reset the frame of UICollectionView? I have looked up API of UICollectionView, i don't see any reset function https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/index.html.

Answer (score 1):

The size of the cells are specified by the layout object of the collection view. Are you using a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`? Try either setting the `itemSize` property of the layout object or implementing the delegate method: `collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:`

You will be able to specify the size of the item (cell) relative to the collection view's bounds there.

Keep in mind that your collection view also needs to be set up so that it resizes with your view controller. If you're using a UICollectionViewController that should be set up automatically. Otherwise, you'll have to constrain your collection view to the bounds of its superview.

**Update:**

You can set the `itemSize` property of the layout directly on the layout:

```
self.layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.collectionView.bounds), 100);
```

or, (better if you're handling rotation or resizing), implement the appropriate delegate call back:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     return CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(collectionView.bounds), 100);
}
```

I'd recommend reading the appropriate `UICollectionView` docs to get more familiar with how collection views and their layout's work:

- [UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout_protocol/index.html)
- [UICollectionViewFlowLayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewFlowLayout_class/index.html)
- [UICollectionView Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: Yes, I am using a UICollectionViewFlowLayout but I am not using a UICollectionViewController.

Comment: Thanks. John. I have did what you suggested which is setting the size in sizeForItemAtIndexPath. I check that the width I return is 414 (width of iphone plus). But when I run it, there are still empty space on right.

Comment: There's a couple things that could be happening. Based on the comments in the other question, sounds like either your `collectionView` is resizing or the cell is resizing - but the content inside the cell isn't. Can you post a screenshot of your nib file? Other things that would help are the output of `NSLog(@"cell frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.frame))` and NSLog(@"content view frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.contentView.frame))` from inside the `-(void)layoutSubviews` call of your `AXFlightSearchResultCell`